# Merge unrelated repos with multiple branch causing conflicts

Tags: java, git

So basically I'm trying to go mono-repo.

I followed some [nice instructions](http://choly.ca/post/git-merge-to-monorepo/). The basic idea is:

1. Create a new git repo.
2. Use `git filter-branch --tree-filter` to move the original repo into a subdirectory.
3. Use `git merge --allow-unrelated` to merge into the new repo.

It works great with `master` branch. But ... I'd like to retain history for another branch `foo`.

So I modify the script like this:

1. Add `-- --all` to `git filter-branch` to do renaming on all logs.
2. Add `git merge`  from `foo` to `foo` into the new repo.

This actually works for some simple repo. But for repo that has a bit of changes in it, it doesn't work for `foo` and causes merge conflict.

Perhaps I understood the principle behind this wrongly. I was not expecting a merge conflict because there simply was nothing on branch `foo` in the new repo.

What did I do wrong? Is it possible to go mono-repo and retain history across different branches?